# Adding UIView in Centre of ViewController | AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

So I have created a Progress Indicator View that I am showing on API calls. I have created a custom UIView Class for it.

Now, everything works fine. But the position of view should be in centre but it's not.

I think I have the constraints right but still its not working.

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import UICircularProgressRing
import HGRippleRadarView


class ProgressIndicator : UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var contentView : UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView : UICircularProgressRing!
    @IBOutlet weak var logoContainerView : UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rippleView : RippleView!

    static let shared = ProgressIndicator()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ProgressIndicator", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)

    }

    public func show(controller : UIViewController) {
        setupLoadingView(controller : controller)
    }

    public func hide() {
        removeLoadingView()
    }

    private func setupLoadingView(controller : UIViewController) {

        controller.view.addSubview(self)

        // adding contrints on main view
        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: controller.view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: controller.view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: controller.view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: controller.view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        controller.view.addConstraints([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])

        // adding constraints on content view

        let leadingConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        let trailingConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        let topConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        let bottomConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        self.addConstraints([leadingConstraint1, trailingConstraint1, topConstraint1, bottomConstraint1])


        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.reloadInputViews()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()


    }

}
```

Here is the result m getting:

[image]

And here is the xib file screenshot

[image]

Comment: There is too much-unrelated code, and why don't you use anchors?

Comment: @Frankenstein ok let me put the necessary code only... and I did use anchors but still got same result so I switched to NSLayoutConstraints.

Comment: If you are using xib why not use auto-layout in that?

Comment: @Frankenstein u didn't understand I guess. The `Content View` is not coming in centre. Check my last screenshot.

Comment: I get that, I'm just asking if you think the issue is regarding the auto-layout maybe you can figure it out. Also, try to provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). that I can try out in maybe in xcode playgrounds.

Comment: where you are adding `ProgressIndicator` to your view ?

Comment: can you share code ? and tell me about the controller you are having issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added constraints but didnt set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`.

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```